# About the density in Girsanov theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have a question about the following version of the Girsanov theorem.

> **Girsanov's Theorem** Let $\theta_t$ be an adapted process satiysfying the Novikov condition. Define a probability measure $\mathbb Q$ by $\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}\Big|_{\mathcal F_t} = \mathcal E(\theta_t)$. Then the stochastic process $t \mapsto W_t - \int_0^t \theta_s ds$ is a standard Wiener process under the measure $\mathbb Q$.

From my understanding, the setting is as follows. We have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, (\mathcal F_t)_t, \mathbb P)$, some index set $T$ and some state space $S$ and the process $\theta$ is a function $\theta: \Omega \times T \to S$ such that each $\theta(\cdot,t) = \theta_t: \Omega\to S$ is measurable.

What I am confused about is the $t$-dependency of the density $\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}\Big|_{\mathcal F_t}$. For each value of $t$, this defines $\mathbb Q|_{\mathcal F_t}$ via $\theta(\cdot,t)$ as $\mathbb Q(U) = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U \mathcal E(\theta_t)] $ for $U\in \mathcal F_t$. But why is this consistent?  Specifically, if $s>t$, then $U\in \mathcal F_t\subset \mathcal F_s$ and so
$$\mathbb Q(U) = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U \mathcal E(\theta_t)] = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U \mathcal E(\theta_s)].$$
But this can only be true if $\theta_s|_U = \theta_t|_U$ for each $U\in \mathcal F_t$. Particularly for $U$ and $\Omega \setminus U$.
Did I make a mistake when applying the definitions?

Comment: It looks like you or this author is confusing $\theta_t$ and ${\cal E}(\theta_t)$. The Radon-Nikodym density $d\mathbb Q/d\mathbb P$ is an exponential martingale usually denonted by ${\cal E}_t$ and the new measure is defined by $d\mathbb Q={\cal E}_T\,d\mathbb P$ for some fixed final time $T$.

Comment: @KurtG. True, i made a type. Fixed now

Comment: In general: When $U\in{\cal F}_T$ we have $\mathbb Q(U)=\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U{\cal E}(\theta_T)]\,.$ By the marginale property of the RN-density you can replace $T$ by $t$ when $U\in{\cal F}_t.$

Comment: @KurtG.So in other words, $\mathbb Q(U) = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U \mathcal E(\theta_t)] = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[1_U \mathcal E(\theta_s)].$ if $\mathcal E(\theta)$ is a martingale. Only then $\mathbb Q$ is well-defined and this is why we need the Novikov condition?

Comment: A probabiliy measure $\mathbb Q$ with density, say, $Z$ w.r.t. $\mathbb P$ is always well-defined when $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[Z]=1$. It is not necessary that $Z$ has anything to do with a martingale. But Girsanov says more. Hint: BM here becomes BM with drift there. Read a decent book about this.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, then I missed the point. I thought that in this situation $Z=Z_t$ depends on $t$ and each value of $t$ defines a different measure $\mathbb Q_t$ (each defined on different sigma algebra). So a priori, it's not clear that these measures "glue" to a well defined global measure $\mu$ with $\mu |_{\mathcal F_t}= \mathbb Q_t = \mathbb P[\cdot Z_t]$.

Comment: Karatzas & Shreve are discussing this adequately in the book *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* where an entire chapter is devoted to the Girsanov theorem. The MSE comment section is not the place to repeat all of this.